# EJB not getting injected into the tested servlet

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, cactus

I am using Cactus to test a servlet which has an injected ejb (EJB 3.0) using @EJB annotation. The servlet is working fine when executed as part of the web application but while running the cactus test it is failing to inject the ejb. I am getting a null pointer exception. Please let me know if there is any limitation of ejb dependency injection in cactus.

Comment: It seems hard to say anything without more details. How are you using Cactus exactly?

Comment: I was using new to instantiate the servlet and hence it was not being managed by the container. I have corrected this issue. thanks for your time and help

Comment: You can place this as an answer and accept it yourself - would make it easier for other people to solve the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using new to instantiate the servlet and hence it was not being managed by the container. I have corrected this issue. thanks for your time and help